# Camera Preview on Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to make  a camera application on Android, no errors in Log-cat but the application doesn't close when i press the back button ; and if i want to open another application camera  after stopping it; the camera is locked !! any hint or ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

```
    public class Capture extends Activity {
    private Camera mCamera;
    private ViewCamera mPreview;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);
        releaseCamera();
        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        Log.d("EyeSeeJD", "getCameraInstance");

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new ViewCamera(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
        Log.d("EyeSeeJD", "addview ");

        preview.addView(mPreview);
    }

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
            // c.lock();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
            Log.d("EyeSeeJD", "can't open camera ");

        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                Log.d("EyeSeeJD",
                        "Error creating media file, check storage permissions ");
                return;
            }

            try {

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("EyeSeeJD", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("EyeSeeJD", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        /*
         * if (mCamera == null) { releaseCamera(); // release the camera
         * immediately on pause event System.exit(0); }
         */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera(); // release the camera immediately on pause event
        // System.exit(0);
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
            // mCamera.unlock();
            mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() { // TODO Auto-generated methodstub
        super.onBackPressed();
        //mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        //mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        //mCamera.release();
    //  mCamera.startPreview();
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
        mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

ViewCamera.java

```
public class ViewCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder = null;
private Camera mCamera = null;

public ViewCamera(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
    // preview.
    try {

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("EyeSeeJD", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

// check if device has camera
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        // this device has a camera
        Log.d("EyeSeeJd", "there is a camera ");

        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        Log.d("EyeSeeJd", "there is no camera ");

        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here
    /*Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(320, 480);
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);*/
    // start preview with new settings
    try {

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        // mCamera.unlock();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("EyeSeeJd",
                "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.

    this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what really happens without following your code in debugger, but there is a chance that you call `Camera.release()` too many times. There may be `NullPointerExeception` somewhere that prevents normal shutdown. There should be only one release in your app, and `onPause()` is a perfect place to call `releaseCamera()`. I don't see why you need to override `onBackPressed()` at all, calling `finish()` from this override is not recommended, and calling `System.exit()` even more so. Also, I would move call to `getCameraInstance()` to `onResume()` or maybe to `onStart()`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your app takes time to close when you press back is that your app is crashing because in onBackPressed() method you are setting mCamera to null and in onDestroy() you are using it again to stop and releasing camera.